# Keynote files won't open

Tags: keynote

Several times lately, when I have tried to open a Keynote file, I get the following message: Unable to open “file name” because it isn't a valid Keynote document. The odd thing is that these are files I created in Keynote and used within the last week. Any idea what's going on? Thank you!!

Comment: Are these files still exactly where they were a week ago, or have they been moved/carried/emailed etc? If in the same place, I'd run Disk Utility & check the drive integrity

Comment: I now have this exact problem - 2 years later. Two days ago, Keynote 5.1.1 was working fine on iMac 10.11.6. Then I got a prompt that a Keynote update was available - did I want to (a) Upgrade (b) Upgrade a copy but keep original or (c) Cancel. Since then, Keynote documents I was working on are corrupted; saved Keynote documents are OK. I can't find a way to upgrade from 5.1.1, Any solution?